# Как делается такая(как на гифке) анимация в Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, подскажите куда смотреть\что читать, чтобы сделать такую анимацию перехода Активити в View элемент
[image: анимация]

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам может помочь `Transition Api`, появившийся в `Android 4.4`.

Суть в том, что `transition` помогает контролировать то, как будет меняться `view` во время анимации.

Более подробно можно почитать тут:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/243363/